# jQuery multihandled range slider fallow to handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using jquery sliders- 1horizontal to track time 0-24h, 1vertical for adjust LED values(later more). I want to achieve when I drag horizontal sliders first handler vertical slider is fallowing, but when dragging second or third handler isn't. Now I'm achieving it by checking mouse position .on("slide", function(e,ui). Maybe there are possible to follow to handler itself? Now vertical slider is fallowing for all handlers because I don't know haw to sort handlers. Maybe some body can direct me in right direction how to solve my problem.

This is my code.

```js
$(".vertical-slider")
                    
    .slider({ 
        min: 0, 
        max: 255,
        orientation: "vertical"
    })         
    .slider("pips", {
        step: "25"
    });
$(".slider").slider({
    min:0,
    max: 24,
    step: 0.0166666666666666667,
    values: [10, 13, 20]
}).slider("pips", {
        rest: "label",
        step:60
    })
    .on("slide", function(e,ui) {

    var posX = e.clientX - 20;
    $(".vertical-slider").slider().css({
       marginLeft:posX
     })
});
```

```css
    .slider.ui-slider {
  border-radius: 20px;
  background: #434d5a;
  border: none;
  height: 10px;
  margin: 1em 4em 4em; }
                    
.slider .ui-slider-handle {
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  top: -2px;
  margin-left: -11px;
  border: 2px solid #fffaf7; }
                    
    .slider .ui-slider-pip.ui-slider-pip-last .ui-slider-label,
    .slider .ui-slider-pip .ui-slider-label,
    .slider .ui-slider-pip.ui-slider-pip-first .ui-slider-label { 
      color: blue;} 
      #vertical-slider {
    height: 150px;
    margin-left: 300px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="us">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>jQuery UI Example Page</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/flick/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery-ui-Slider-Pips/1.11.4/jquery-ui-slider-pips.css">
 <!-- include the jQuery and jQuery UI scripts -->
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery-ui-Slider-Pips/1.11.4/jquery-ui-slider-pips.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Slider -->
<br><br>
<div class="vertical-slider" id="vertical-slider"></div>
<div class="slider" id="slider"></div>

 </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long time but it is more or less done...
If somebody have any suggestion haw to improve code, add comments

```js
var c = parseInt(getComputedStyle(document.body).fontSize) *4 ;
var atkape = parseInt($('.vertical-slider').slider().css("width"))*.5;
var val0;
    var val1;
    var val2;
    var sliderwidtgh;
    var max;


$(".slider").slider({
    min:0,
    max: 24,
    step: 0.0166666666666666667,
    values: [10, 13, 20,22],
     create: function(e, ui){
     sliderwidtgh = parseInt($('.slider').slider().css("width"));
     val0 = $('.slider').slider("values")[0];
    val1 = $('.slider').slider("values")[1];
    val2 = $('.slider').slider("values")[2];
    val3 = $('.slider').slider("values")[3];
    max = $('.slider').slider("option", "max")
         $(".vertical-slider").slider().css({
       marginLeft:sliderwidtgh * val0 / max + c +5
     })
     $(".vertical-slider2").slider().css({
       marginLeft:(sliderwidtgh * val1 / max )-(sliderwidtgh * val0 / max + c -15)
     })
     $(".vertical-slider3").slider().css({
       marginLeft:(sliderwidtgh * val2 / max)-(sliderwidtgh * val1 / max + c - 15)
     })
      $(".vertical-slider4").slider().css({
       marginLeft:(sliderwidtgh * val3 / max)-(sliderwidtgh * val2 / max + c - 15)
     })
    }
}).slider("pips", {
        rest: "label",
        step:60
    })
    .on("slide", function(e,ui) {
    sliderwidtgh = parseInt($('.slider').slider().css("width"));
    val0 = $('.slider').slider("values")[0];
    val1 = $('.slider').slider("values")[1];
    val2 = $('.slider').slider("values")[2];
    val3 = $('.slider').slider("values")[3];
    max = $('.slider').slider("option", "max")
    $(".vertical-slider").slider().css({
       marginLeft:sliderwidtgh * val0 / max + c +5
     })
     $(".vertical-slider2").slider().css({
       marginLeft:(sliderwidtgh * val1 / max)-(sliderwidtgh * val0 / max + c - 15)
     })
     $(".vertical-slider3").slider().css({
       marginLeft:(sliderwidtgh * val2 / max)-(sliderwidtgh * val1 / max + c - 15)
     })
     $(".vertical-slider4").slider().css({
       marginLeft:(sliderwidtgh * val3 / max)-(sliderwidtgh * val2 / max + c - 15)
     })
    
});
$(".vertical-slider")              
    .slider({ 
        min: 0, 
        max: 255,
        orientation: "vertical"
    })         
    .slider("pips", {
        step: "25.5"
    });
$(".vertical-slider2")              
    .slider({ 
        min: 0, 
        max: 255,
        orientation: "vertical"
    })         
    .slider("pips", {
        step: "25.5"
    });
$(".vertical-slider3")              
    .slider({ 
        min: 0, 
        max: 255,
        orientation: "vertical"
    })         
    .slider("pips", {
        step: "25.5"
    });
  $(".vertical-slider4")              
    .slider({ 
        min: 0, 
        max: 255,
        orientation: "vertical"
    })         
    .slider("pips", {
        step: "25.5"
    });
function Test(){
var val=$('.slider').slider("values")[0];
var val1=$('.vertical-slider').slider("value");
  $("#labeloutput").text( "You selected "  + Math.floor(val)+ " and " + Math.round((val - Math.floor(val)) / 0.016667) + "and " + val1);
}
```

```css
.slider.ui-slider {
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: #434d5a;
  border: none;
  height: 10px;
  margin: 1em 4em 4em; }
                    
.slider .ui-slider-handle {
  border-radius: 2px;
  height: 12px;
  width: 4px;
  top: -2px;
  margin-left: 0px;}
                    
    .slider .ui-slider-pip.ui-slider-pip-last .ui-slider-label,
    .slider .ui-slider-pip .ui-slider-label,
    .slider .ui-slider-pip.ui-slider-pip-first .ui-slider-label { 
      color: blue;} 
      
 .vertical-slider.ui-slider,
 .vertical-slider2.ui-slider,
 .vertical-slider3.ui-slider,
 .vertical-slider4.ui-slider{
  background: #434d5a;
  width: 10px;
  border: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom:-15px;}
  
  .vertical-slider .ui-slider-handle,
  .vertical-slider2 .ui-slider-handle,
 .vertical-slider3 .ui-slider-handle,
 .vertical-slider4 .ui-slider-handle{
  border-radius: 2px;
  height: 4px;
  width: 12px;
  margin-left:2px;
  margin-bottom:-2px;
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="us">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>jQuery UI Example Page</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/flick/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery-ui-Slider-Pips/1.11.4/jquery-ui-slider-pips.css">
 <!-- include the jQuery and jQuery UI scripts -->
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery-ui-Slider-Pips/1.11.4/jquery-ui-slider-pips.js"></script>

 
</head>
<body>

<!-- Slider -->
<br><br>
<div class="vertical">
  <p class="vertical-slider"></p>
  <p class="vertical-slider2"></p>
  <p class="vertical-slider3"></p>
  <p class="vertical-slider4"></p>
</div>
<div class="slider" id="slider"></div>
<p id="labeloutput" >You</p>
 <button id="desa" type="button" onclick="Test()">Click Me!</button> 
 </body>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".vertical-slider").slider().css({
   marginLeft:posX
 })
```

Perhaps you should not use a wildcard selector `$(".vertical-slider")` but something relative to your element e.g.

```
$(el).closest(".vertical-slider")
```

Comment: You can probably use the `<>` in the editor to provide a working example.